# Grouping bits in a union or using bitarray

Tags: python, bit, bitflags

I need to implement grouped bits in the following code or use the bitarray implementation to achive this:

e.g: The bits logout,Idle should belong to a group say "close", if any of the bits logout or Idle are 1 then I should be able to read the  close  bit as 1.

Inshort I have a heirachy of flags with parent child relationships needed to be represented as bits like:

```
close
 logout
 switch
 hibernate

open
 poweron
 start

run

operate
```

The parent flag is the bitwise OR of its child, so only all the child flags would be stored and setting the virtual parent flag would set all its children. Ideally I would like to use the [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) implementation to achieve this.

### What I want:

```
print flags.close
flags.close=1 ## this would set all the children flags to 1
print flags
print logout
```

I guess this can be accomplished by inheriting from the bitarray class.

Comment: You need properties for your class, read http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Comment: @MichaelButscher I want to use the bitarray implementation for this